# Uncaught TypeError: <my obj>.validate is not a function

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-cli

I'm just getting started with [ember-validations](https://github.com/dockyard/ember-validations), but I'm getting the error:  `Uncaught TypeError: <my obj>.validate is not a function`

Here is my object that extends `EmberValidations`:

```
import EmberValidations from 'ember-validations';

export default Ember.Object.extend(EmberValidations, {

  name  : undefined,
  total : undefined,

  validations: {
    name  : { presence: true },
    total : { presence: true }
  }
});
```

And here is the code that throws the error:

```
  var category = Category.create({
    name  : 'Bill',
    total : 0
  });
  category.validate();  // Error thrown here
```

I feel like I'm missing something really simple.  Any ideas?

---

**Edit**

I'm importing `Category` as follows:

```
import Category from 'step/models/category';
```

Comment: Are you importing Category?

Comment: Yeah, I think the import's working (see my edit).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `EmberValidations.Mixin` Mixin not `EmberValidations` Object itself.

Comment: Hm, that results in the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'lookup' of undefined` in the line where I create the category `var category = Category.create({...` :/